# 'grep' a file name, but only show

Tags: bash, grep

I have files that are named ACC160-MASTER-201503, ACC160L-MASTER-201503 and IS160-MASTER-201503. I'm basically trying to output the first few letters (in the example, just ACC and IS) and not the numbers. After that I need another grep to only grab up to the `-` (in the example, ACC160, ACC160L, and IS160).

Comment: you're right. that's not something you use grep for. grep is for FINDING things. once you've found that thing, grep's job is done. you'd need other tools to cut down the output, e.g. awk/sed

Comment: You probably *can* do this using grep's `-o` option but you probably *shouldn't* do this with grep. Where are the file names coming from? What bits of them do you need at various times? What do you need to do with those bits of the names?

Comment: Etan Reisner- I'm creating a bash file that I'm using to do curtain things. But in order for it to work properly. I need to pull this information as mentioned for curtain variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the filename until the first '-' then `grep -oP ".*?(?=-)"` should do the trick.

- `-o` is the only-matching option
- `-P` enables Perl syntax
- `.*?` is a reluctant quantifiers, it reads while looking for the next motif in the regex
- `(?=-)` is a lookahead tag: it tells you what to expect (-) after the matching substring

Comment: Thanks for the information echo ACC160-MASTER-201503 | grep -oP ".*?(?=-)" outputs
ACC160
MASTER.

Comment: `grep -oP "^.*?(?=-)"`will work, `^` anchors the pattern to the beginning of the line.

Comment: CaptainCap - Thanks! With that I can get the other part. echo ACC160L-MASTER-201503 | grep -oP "^.*?(?=-)" | grep -o '^.[a-zA-Z]*' If anyone cares to know

Answer (score 1):

If this is bash/ksh/zsh/sh/..., just use [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```sh
for file in ACC160-MASTER-201503 ACC160L-MASTER-201503 IS160-MASTER-201503; do
    alnum=${file%%-*}          # remove the first "-" and following chars
    alpha=${alnum%%[0-9]*}     # remove the first digit and all following chars

    echo "$file => $alnum => $alpha"
done
```

```
ACC160-MASTER-201503 => ACC160 => ACC
ACC160L-MASTER-201503 => ACC160L => ACC
IS160-MASTER-201503 => IS160 => IS
```